# MS SQL Join on dateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a query that joins two tables.
The join is done on several columns, including a dateTime column.
The problem that I have at the moment is that the one dateTime column stores milliseconds whereas the other table is populated from a file which does not contain milliseconds
Because of this the join will never return results.

Is there any way via SQl to ignore the milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If aTable.date contains millisenconds and bTable.date does not, to compare them:

```
... WHERE convert(varchar, aTable.date, 120) = bTable.date
```

converting datetime to varchar with arg2=120 produce this format: [ODBC canonical yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Which adds another explicit conversion back to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

This still has a function but avoid strings and conversions

```
WHERE
    aTable.date >= bTable.date
    AND
    aTable.date < DATEADD(second, 1, bTable.date)
```